# slide div left by #px when mouseleave

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a menu div slide 200px left when I mouse out.

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<nav id="menuLeft">
    <div id="menuLeft-toggle">
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        accordion menu in here
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        accordion menu in here
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
        accordion menu in here
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have a toggle div and few menu panels (it's for eLearning).

The layout is as follows:

- The nav div is on the left side of the screen and is 200px wide by
  100% high
- The menuLeft-toggle div runs down the right side of the
  menuLeft nav div
- The panel divs stack vertically within the menuLeft div

I am already using JS (hasClass and removeClass) to toggle the nav div open and closed manually when clicking the menuLeft-toggle div but need to auto-hide (slide) the nav div on mouse out by 200px to the left so we don't hide the toggle div.

How can I accomplish having the div slide (i.e. .hide(400) ) by only 200px AND still have it able to open when the menuLeft-toggle div is clicked?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is quite what you're looking for, but using the `:hover` pseudo class could be used to trigger hiding the menu.

The menu would default to 'hidden' - (off the screen).  Applying the `:hover` class zeroes out the `left` property of the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/fhfe1gey/

Comment: I really like this solution. Using it has allowed me to remove the related JS using only HTML and CSS. The only thing is, I'm unable to style the menuLeft-toggle div but am sure I can get through that part. Awesome and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to give it a CSS transition of, let's say, 2 seconds. This means it takes 2 seconds to slide, so it doesn't look like it's just snapping to the side. Obviously, you can change this to what you like, and if you don't want it, you don't need it.

```
#menuLeft{
    transition: 2s;
}
```

To make the `div` move left by 200px on mouse leave:

```
function moveMenuToLeft(){
    document.getElementById('menuLeft').style.left = '-200px'; //change 'left' to 'marginLeft' if it isnt fixed on the screen
}
document.getElementById('menuLeft').onmouseleave = moveMenuToLeft;
```

To make the `div` move back into place again when the button is clicked:

```
function moveMenuBack(){
    document.getElementById('menuLeft').style.left = '0'; //change 'left' to 'marginLeft' if needed
}
document.getElementById('menuLeft-toggle').onclick = moveMenuBack;
```

Since the `div` is 400px wide, but you need 200px to remain visible, moving it left by only 200px keeps that right 200px in view.

Comment: I like this solution using JS, but after trying this solution, the menuLeft-toggle div still remains 200px to the right of the left margin while the menuLeft div hides. I can then click the menuLeft-toggle div and it will go to 0px separately.

Comment: Do you mean that the menuLeft-toggle div is hanging out the side of the main div?